# Как в if добавлять значение переменной?

Tags: javascript

Вот код
Как вывести переменную уже с добавленным значением?

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    var keyW, keyA, keyS, keyD;
    
    var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
    
    keyW = 87; keyUp = 38;
    keyA = 65; keyLeft = 37;
    keyS = 83; keyDown = 40;
    keyD = 68; keyRight = 39;
   
    var xn, yn;
    
    var x = xn + 'px';
    var y = yn + 'px';
    
    if (event.keyCode == keyW) {
        return yn += 10;
    }
    console.log(y);
});
```

Comment: а что сейчас не так?

Comment: Достаточно убрать `return`

Answer (score 1):

Попытаем угадайку

```js
var xn = 0, yn = 0;
        
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    var keyW, keyA, keyS, keyD;
    
    var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
    
    keyW = 87; keyUp = 38;
    keyA = 65; keyLeft = 37;
    keyS = 83; keyDown = 40;
    keyD = 68; keyRight = 39;       
    
    if (event.keyCode == keyW) {
        yn += 10;
    }
    
    var x = xn + 'px';
    var y = yn + 'px';
    
    console.log(y);
});
```

Comment: Леха пари кто угадал +1 от аппонента :)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое хотели?

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    var keyW, keyA, keyS, keyD;
    
    var keyUp, keyDown, keyLeft, keyRight;
    
    keyW = 87; keyUp = 38;
    keyA = 65; keyLeft = 37;
    keyS = 83; keyDown = 40;
    keyD = 68; keyRight = 39;
    
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case keyUp: case keyW:  x+=10; break;
      case keyDown: case  keyS:  x-=10; break;
      case keyRight: case keyD:  y+=10; break;
      case keyLeft: case keyA:  y-=10; break;
    }
   
    
    console.log(`x =${x}, y = ${y}`);    
});
```